# Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Untrusted URL when I load Youtube video inside WebView on JavaFX

Tags: promise, youtube, javafx-webengine

[image]

When I load a Youtube video using WebView directly from YT, I get all the page data, but the video stays charging without showing the video itself. This issue is new because the previous week that worked adequately.

I suppose that Youtube has made some changes to prevent embedding video pages inside JavaFX WebView component.

Please use the following repository to see a test.

https://bitbucket.org/diegoluisr/javafx-webview-youtube-test/src/master/[enter link description here](https://bitbucket.org/diegoluisr/javafx-webview-youtube-test/src/master/)

WebKit browser prints in the console the following lines...

```
Console: [https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflPI0brM/en_US/base.js:39] Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Untrusted URL: https://r3---sn-qpgxju8jva-cvbe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1564559165&ei=3PJAXYPFN7n6j-8Podm9WA&ip=191.102.199.174&id=o-AFpZ9-9BjKhhYLbO9zoBJ-koAlgU4_rl5mhm-RAcZPp2&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-qpgxju8jva-cvbe%2Csn-hp57knly&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=24&ctier=L&initcwndbps=236250&mime=video%2Fmp4&ratebypass=yes&dur=10.100&lmt=1563964109911459&mt=1564537439&fvip=2&c=WEB&txp=5316222&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cctier%2Cmime%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRgIhAND23sayeeFGInqso6n2wt5VI1-8CmEwn3BS7KEqdFZ0AiEAokZIzzORQLnQLDhnoUmK6gSJP1FxDnpJAIcPNOVxoxg%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRQIgH9Mxi8qnf2E1yvcvfA8gjeJTBKe_kKBklEhjz82gWK4CIQCX6D8qZbu-Dpy-NkCRcluo-OOLSzuu8mgEwgni5_8RFA%3D%3D
Console: [https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflPI0brM/en_US/base.js:39] Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Untrusted URL: https://r4---sn-qpgxju8jva-cvbe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1564559175&ei=5_JAXe6MCoS2lAOI14eoBA&ip=191.102.199.174&id=o-ALfOT4rp_IeL6a86s4a2nTlmva4YgQkA9yc_o-ma4_hG&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-qpgxju8jva-cvbe%2Csn-hp57knzz&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=3&pl=24&ctier=L&initcwndbps=236250&mime=video%2Fmp4&ratebypass=yes&dur=119.559&lmt=1563514693761974&mt=1564537439&fvip=4&c=WEB&txp=5316222&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cctier%2Cmime%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRQIhAI-C_mVNjdJNzAK249RkB62Blm7jw1_FjwQvkebmhCMUAiBOzmlsdMCZriM9VSmcAVM-BzxzGpcK49kHGg8izPQfVA%3D%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRAIgMRZJB2yOLTSlIgblsfaMsK56HcO6MQ6bklYQDnLczM4CIGXeJsTlmhBTDodytkm2jO5Gc6SmY6Q6sjQmwVrUXnvH
Console: [https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflPI0brM/en_US/base.js:39] Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Untrusted URL: https://r2---sn-qpgxju8jva-cvbe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1564559162&ei=2vJAXYWoHOXbj-8Prs-DgAo&ip=191.102.199.174&id=o-AO7C5x6ZIyPXAr2qK_vIPflPjs-AOMY2IJVZliAV72Cp&itag=18&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-qpgxju8jva-cvbe%2Csn-hp57kn6e&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=24&initcwndbps=236250&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=19015393&ratebypass=yes&dur=348.856&lmt=1537207191333104&mt=1564537439&fvip=2&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRQIgW0bSjfFcOWJAwx2_jlafwhDh5-QSE4QaHLllKQUCoXgCIQCcEWzrSiuhAAj9ibUukTnM9_Z7Ln8u8ZbxH4gfqid-fw%3D%3D
```

You could notice three console lines, that is because the player tried to load 2 Advertising video before the "Alice in Chains" video.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem working around it; I have to use a commercial component named JxBrowser. This component uses a chromium implementation (version 69) that allows the embed player to work, and disable gestures required to autoplay.

You could find more information on the component website
https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser